# OpenCL: Correct results on CPU not on GPU: how to manage memory correctly?

Tags: c++, opencl, gpgpu, nvidia

```
__kernel void CKmix(__global short* MCL, __global short* MPCL,__global short *C,  int S,  int B)
{       
    unsigned int i=get_global_id(0);
    unsigned int ii=get_global_id(1);
    MCL[i]+=MPCL[B*ii+i+C[ii]+S];
}
```

Kernel seams ok, it compiles successfully, and I have obtained the correct results using the CPU as a device, but that was when I had the program release and and recreate my memory objects each time the kernel is called, which for my testing purpose is about 16000 times.

The code I am posting is where I am at now, trying to use pinned memory and mapping.

```
OpenCLProgram = clCreateProgramWithSource(hContext[Plat-1][Dev-1],11, OpenCLSource, NULL ,NULL);
clBuildProgram(OpenCLProgram, 0,NULL,NULL, NULL,NULL);
ocKernel = clCreateKernel(OpenCLProgram, "CKmix", NULL);
```

This is also successful.  The reason I have a 2d array of contexts is that I iterate through all platforms and devices and allow the user to select the platform and device to use.

```
WorkSize[0]=SN;
WorkSize[1]=NF;  

PinnedCCL = clCreateBuffer(hContext[Plat-1][Dev-1], CL_MEM_READ_WRITE| CL_MEM_ALLOC_HOST_PTR, sizeof(short) *NF, NULL, NULL);
PinnedMCL = clCreateBuffer(hContext[Plat-1][Dev-1], CL_MEM_READ_WRITE | CL_MEM_ALLOC_HOST_PTR, sizeof(short) * Z*NF, NULL, NULL);
PinnedMO =  clCreateBuffer(hContext[Plat-1][Dev-1], CL_MEM_READ_WRITE | CL_MEM_ALLOC_HOST_PTR, sizeof(short) * Z,NULL, NULL);
PinnedMTEMP =  clCreateBuffer(hContext[Plat-1][Dev-1], CL_MEM_READ_WRITE | CL_MEM_ALLOC_HOST_PTR, sizeof(short) * Z,NULL, NULL);

DevComboCCL = clCreateBuffer(hContext[Plat-1][Dev-1], CL_MEM_READ_WRITE, sizeof(short) *NF, NULL, NULL);    
DevMappedMCL = clCreateBuffer(hContext[Plat-1][Dev-1], CL_MEM_READ_WRITE , sizeof(short) * Z*NF, NULL,NULL);
DevMO =  clCreateBuffer(hContext[Plat-1][Dev-1], CL_MEM_READ_WRITE , sizeof(short) * Z,NULL, NULL);

MO = (short*) clEnqueueMapBuffer(hCmdQueue[Plat-1][Dev-1], PinnedMO, CL_TRUE, CL_MAP_READ, 0, sizeof(short)*Z, 0, NULL, NULL, NULL);
CCL = (short*) clEnqueueMapBuffer(hCmdQueue[Plat-1][Dev-1], PinnedCCL, CL_TRUE, CL_MAP_WRITE, 0, sizeof(short)*NF, 0, NULL, NULL,NULL);
MCL = (short*) clEnqueueMapBuffer(hCmdQueue[Plat-1][Dev-1], PinnedMCL, CL_TRUE, CL_MAP_WRITE, 0, sizeof(short)*Z*NF, 0, NULL, NULL, NULL);
MTEMP = (short*) clEnqueueMapBuffer(hCmdQueue[Plat-1][Dev-1], PinnedMTEMP, CL_TRUE, CL_MAP_READ, 0, sizeof(short)*Z, 0, NULL, NULL, NULL);

for (n=0; n < Z; ++n) {
    MTEMP[n]=0;
    }

clSetKernelArg(ocKernel, 0, sizeof(cl_mem), (void*) &DevMO);
clSetKernelArg(ocKernel, 1, sizeof(cl_mem), (void*) &DevMCL);    
clSetKernelArg(ocKernel, 2, sizeof(cl_mem), (void*) &DevCCL);
clSetKernelArg(ocKernel, 3, sizeof(int),    (void*) &SH);
clSetKernelArg(ocKernel, 4, sizeof(int),    (void*) &SN);
```

The above constitutes my initialization, and the rest below, happens repeatedly.

```
clEnqueueWriteBuffer(hCmdQueue[Plat-1][Dev-1], DevMCL, CL_TRUE, 0, Z*NF*sizeof(short), MCL, 0, NULL, NULL);
clEnqueueWriteBuffer(hCmdQueue[Plat-1][Dev-1], DevCCL, CL_TRUE, 0, NF*sizeof(short), CCL, 0, NULL, NULL);
clEnqueueWriteBuffer(hCmdQueue[Plat-1][Dev-1], DevMO, CL_TRUE, 0, Z*sizeof(short), MTEMP, 0, NULL, NULL);

clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(hCmdQueue[Plat-1][Dev-1], ocKernel, 2, NULL, WorkSize, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL);
clEnqueueReadBuffer(hCmdQueue[Plat-1][Dev-1],DevMO, CL_TRUE, 0, Z * sizeof(short),(void*) MO , 0, NULL, NULL);
```

I have checked for errors, and I am not getting any errors.  The kernel is launched many times repeatedly with fresh data.  I am not sure where I am doing wrong.

NVIDIA 550 ti compute capability 2.1,
 latest Dev Driver,
 Cuda SDK 4.0,

Comment: So what exactly is going wrong?

Comment: @Grizzly  I am not getting the correct results (MO).  I also get different results when I use the GPU vs CPU.

Comment: So what results do you get and what did you expect?

Comment: @Grizzly the kernel is launched within a nested loop, the outer loop iterates 7 times, and the inner about 15,000 times.  The innerloop derives the results for a particular set of data, and the outerloop iterates through sets of data.  So I get 7 results which are the addition of the elements in MO.  The correct results as I get without openCL, are :391725892, 616085276, 635390637, 682414482, 700946018, 749609786, 772387246.  The results on GPU with openCL: 220257766, 401009434, 551268540, 678976664, 945593751, 1241266605, 1504909805.  The GPU results vary though, by a couple of thousand.

Comment: When I run on the CPU, I get the correct result for the first set of data, and incorrect results for the next 6 sets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if its the only problem with the code, but this:

```
unsigned int i=get_global_id(0);
unsigned int ii=get_global_id(1);
MCL[i]+=MPCL[B*ii+i+C[ii]+S];
```

is definitely not a good idea. You will generally get multiple threads working on the same `global_id(0)`, so several threads might try to update `MCL[i]` simultaneous (note that `+=` is not atomic). I would assume that for the CPU there are not enough threads generated to show such a behaviour in most of the cases, while having thousands of threads on the gpu will almost surely lead to problems.

The most reasonable way to do this is to have only a 1 dimensional workingset and for each thread accumulate all values which go to one position:

```
unsigned int i=get_global_id(0);
short accum = MCL[i]; //or 0, if thats the start
for(int ii = 0; ii < size; ++ii)
  accum += MPCL[B*ii+i+C[ii]+S];
MCL[i] = accum;
```

Of course that might or might not be feasible. If it isn't the fix probably won't be quite that simple.

Comment: Is `global_id(0)` unique for 1-dimensional workingsets, but not for 2- or 3-dimensional workingsets?

Comment: @SteveBlackwell: For a 1 dimensional workingset you have ids 0..N where each thread gets one of those. For a 2 dim. you have ids [0..N, 0..M] where each combination happens once, so you get M threads sharing the same `global_id(0)` (but having different `global_id(1)`)

Comment: @Grizzly: Your solution works.  I am now getting the correct results on the GPU!  I still have to figure out how to optimize it though because it's only about 20 percent faster than in serial on the CPU, and 3 times slower than on the CPU using openMP.  I am going to try and incorporate the use of shared memory, and work on understanding coalescence and alignment.  Thanks!

Comment: @MVTCplusplus: Well that was to be expected considering your most likely less then optimal access pattern for coalescing. Maybe this answer of mine helps your understanding of coalescence: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3858174/201270

Comment: Making the work size a multiple of 32 made a big difference.     `while (WorkSize % 32 != 0) --WorkSize;` , or  `++WorkSize`, Makes the process about three times faster.

Comment: @MVTCplusplus: I'm not sure what you mean with `while (WorkSize % 32 != 0) --WorkSize;`, but for the local worksize that is advisable too. Completely forgot about this point since I basically always use a local work group size of 128, which seemed to be close to optimal for most cards.

Comment: Interestingly, before adjusting the global worksize to a value divisible by 32, the program was 3 times slower, and my GPU usage meter would peak.  After adjusting to multiple of 32 it is not only 3 times faster, but also my GPU meter only goes up to 30 percent.

Comment: @Grizzly setting the local work size to 128 improved the performance by an additional 10%.