# Why do I get different numerical results running a kernel on a CPU vs GPU?

Tags: opencl, gpgpu

I'm enqueuing a kernel with clEnqueueNDRangeKernel. With local_work_size equal to 1, I get the same numerical results on the CPU as the GPU. With local_work_size equal to NULL, I get different results. Note that I'm not talking about the speed of execution; just the actual results.

What general issues could cause this to be the case? Does this suggest a memory leak that is only apparent in the GPU when local_work_size = NULL?

kernel: https://gist.github.com/dprentiss/10982016
EDIT: gist updated to reflect recent changes.

[OpenCL: Correct results on CPU not on GPU: how to manage memory correctly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8823862/opencl-correct-results-on-cpu-not-on-gpu-how-to-manage-memory-correctly) Has similar symptoms, but my kernel addresses (to my knowledge) only one global_id(0).

Comment: Are the results not equal, or simply wrong?

Comment: With local_work_size = 1, I get correct results from the CPU and GPU. With local_work_size = NULL, I get the correct answer from the CPU and the wrong answer from the GPU.

Comment: Your code doesn't seem to depend on any local work-item IDs, so it should work in theory. When you set local_work_size equal (LWS) to NULL you're basically saying "let the device chose the most appropriate LWS". CPU devices usually chose LWS=1, while GPU usually choses 64, 128, etc. Test your kernel with different explicit LWSs on both the CPU and GPU and compare the results. If the LWS affects the results on both devices, your kernel has a problem somewhere. If, however, the larger LWS only affect the result on the GPU, the problem may be more subtle.